# Kraft Macmillan inequality explanation

Tags: it.information-theory

I am going through some questions and answers regarding Information Theory and I found this question and its solution. Can some one explain this solution to me.

We would like to encode a sequence of symbols that come from an alphabet with d+3 symbols. We want to encode symbols  a_1,a_2,and a_3 using code words that are three bits long and symbols a_4,a_5,…,a_(d+1) with code words that are eight bits long. What is the maximum value of d for which this will be possible, if the code must be uniquely decidable?

and the answer is:

The codeword lengths are possible if and only if they satisfy the Kraft-MacMillan inequality,which in this case is 
1/2^3 +1/2^3 +1/2^3 +d/2^8 <= 1 
This is equivalent to 
d/256<=5/8
which is equivalent to d<=160. The maximum value possible value of d is therefore 160.
what is the function d+3 , and where we used it . How 5/8 appears in equation.

What is the effect of d+3 symbols on all this scenario. If I change it to d+1, what is the effect of it

Comment: Cross-posted on Math.SE: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1414536/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted. If you don't get a satisfying answer after a week or so, feel free to flag for migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's just in the first inequality (the Kraft inequality): you sum over all the symbols $1/2^{\text{length of encoding}}$. There are 3 symbols of length $3$ bits and $d$ symbols of length $8$ bits, so that's how you get the first inequality. (Also, does your question have a typo? $a_4,a_5,\dots,a_{d+3}$ rather than $\dots,a_{d+1}$.) The $5/8$ comes from simplifying the inequality: you get $3/8 + d/256 \leq 1$, which is equivalent to $d/256 \leq 5/8$.

Comment: One more question, What is the effect of d+3 symbols on all this scenario. If I change it to d+1, what is the effect of it @usul

Comment: @MuneebulHassan, in the first inequality, we sum over all the symbols. There are $d+3$ symbols total. $3$ of them have length $3$ and $d$ have length $8$. So that's $3\cdot(1/2^3) + d\cdot (1/2^8) \leq 1$. If we only had $d+1$ symbols, there would be $3$ with length $3$ and $d-2$ with length $8$. So the inequality would be $3\cdot(1/2^3) + (d-2)\cdot(1/2^8) \leq 1$.

Comment: @usul: He has already asked the same question on Math Stackexchange which I answered.